# javascript uncaught TypeError: ")".find is not a function for save tab selection on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to save my last tab choice on page refresh. I am very close and seem to be having trouble on the last line. I found out that since my page elements are dynamically created I need to delegate the event with $(document), however, it doesn't seem to like the line below. Any ideas why?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(".tabs").tabs();
            var tabIndex = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('activeTab')) + 1;
            console.log("local storage value parseInt: " + tabIndex);
            if(tabIndex != null){
                    console.log("I am in the if statement: " + localStorage.getItem('activeTab'));
                    //$('.tabs > ul > li:nth-child('+ (tabIndex)  +')').find('a').click();
                    $(document).on("click", ".tabs > ul > li:nth-child(" + tabIndex + ")".find('a'), function(e) {})
            }         
        $(document).on("click", ".tab-links a", function(e) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            var curTab = $('.tab-links').find('.active')[0].id;
            console.log("This is the currentTab value: " + curTab.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ));
            var curTabIndex = (curTab.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ) - 1);
            localStorage.setItem('activeTab', curTabIndex);
        });
    </script>

<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li id="t1"><a href="#tab1" class="tab1a">One</a></li>
        <li id="t2"><a href="#tab2" class="tab2a">Two</a></li>
        <li id="t3"><a href="#tab3" class="tab3a">Three</a></li>
        <li id="t4"><a href="#tab4" class="tab4a">Four</a></li>
        <li id="t5"><a href="#tab5" class="tab5a">Five</a></li>
        <li id="t5"><a href="#tab6" class="tab6a">Six</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active" >
            <?php   include("tab_1.html");    ?>
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab" >
            <?php   include("tab_2.html");   ?>
        </div>

        <div id="tab3" class="tab" >
            <?php   include("tab_3.html");    ?>
        </div>

        <div id="tab4" class="tab active">
            <?php  include("tab_4.html"); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="tab5" class="tab active">
            <?php include("tab_5.html"); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="tab6" class="tab active">
            <?php include("tab_6.html") ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems to be complaining about this line. I am trying to use

```
$(document).on("click", ".tabs > ul > li:nth-child(" + tabIndex + ")".find('a'), function(e) {})
```

Uncaught TypeError: ")".find is not a function

Comment: You have `li:nth-child(" + tabIndex + ")"`

Comment: `if` condtion does not have a closing `}`

Comment: I actually do have the closing bracket in the if statement in my actual code. I just edited my code above. Stil Getting the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put jQuery code as part of the selector argument, so you can't use .find() here as it's not part of the spec for jQuery/CSS selectors.

Try this instead:

`$(document).on("click", ".tabs > ul > li:nth-child(" + tabIndex + ") a", function(e) {});`

Here is a list of valid selector rules for jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Okay, when I add that. I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" now.

Comment: As another commenter pointed out, you're missing a closing } on one of your if statements. Did you fix that first?

Comment: Yes, that was actually in my original code. not sure how that was missed. I updated my code above.

Comment: Is this error on the same line, or a different one?

Comment: it's on the same line, but it shows error (red underline) towards the end of that line.

Comment: @kkmoslehpour see my updated answer. You can't use .find() in that argument because you need to provide the selector. You can't execute .find() there.

Comment: Nice, that worked. However, it is not selecting my last selected tab on page refresh. Am i missing something else? I get the following output systemTest.php:85 local storage value parseInt: 6
11:23:03.267 systemTest.php:87 I am in the if statement: 5 So my values check out good, but it doesn't click the tabs.

Comment: @kkmoslehpour I recommend posting a new question as it sounds like a separate issue.